# MySql returns incorrect date value in select query

Tags: php, mysql, date, yii

In my `Yii` - `PHP` application I used mysql database. In a table I have a date value column of datatype `timestamp`. After inserting a row the column gets the correct date and time value. But when I try to fetch the datas from table i got a different date value.

```
Table contains this value - 2015-02-02 15:59:13

But after select I got  - 2015-02-02 10:29:13
```

Every time there is a `-5:30` difference between the times.

Here the query builder code

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
   ->select('*')
   ->from('table_name')
   ->where('id =:id', array(':id'=>4))
   ->queryRow();
```

Don't know why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you changed the timezone by any chance?

Comment: Show us your select query.

Comment: This is not the timezone issue - the difference is not a multitude of 1 hour. I  guess it's a problem with a query.

Comment: I smell either an unwanted update on the record with current time or an unwanted reassignment while reading/debugging... still to find out we need the query, as other before me told. :)

Comment: question edited now...

Comment: @SherinJose with that query you get the correct row with the correct data except for the date column?

Comment: yes...only the date value is incorrect

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any automatic update of the date directly in mysql table? ...  I'm still guessing here, because I cannot see the actual query and table...

Comment: Is that `2015-02-02 09:02:10` always give same value in 2nd, 3rd, next next queries?

Comment: sorry everyone, there is a small mistake in the question , I edited the time values given. @ColourDalnet It always given a `-5:30` difference

Comment: @SherinJose looks like timezone issue. Some of timezones has X:30 delta. Like Island of Newfoundland (3:30)

Comment: eheh it turned out that @acontell was right even if from the question he was... wrong.

Comment: Default timezone was `UTC` . Now i changed it to `Asia/Kolkata`, then it saves time as `+5:30` to my local time and then returns correct local time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to properly close the question, since we understood it was a problem of timezone setting:

```
  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Inside my app.js file I added `timezone: 'gmt'` to the connection section.